# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined on ko.cleanNode

Tags: knockout.js

```
  var ready;

  ready = function() {
    var imageChooser, productChooser;
    productChooser = function() {
      var self;
      self = this;
      self.quantityId = ko.observable(1);
      self.quantityText = ko.observable('QTY');
      self.genderId = ko.observable(1);
      self.sizeId = ko.observable(1);
      self.colorId = ko.observable(1);
      self.fullSize = ko.observable('SIZE');
      this.setGenderAndSize = function(stringtoparse, thestring) {
        var values;
        values = stringtoparse.split(":");
        self.fullSize("SIZE: " + thestring);
        self.genderId(values[0]);
        self.sizeId(values[1]);
      };
      this.setQuantity = function(quantity) {
        self.quantityId(quantity);
        self.quantityText("QTY: " + quantity);
      };
    };
    imageChooser = function() {
      this.clicked = ko.observable();
      this.setBigImage = (function(message) {
        alert(message);
      }).bind(this);
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new productChooser(), $("#genderAndSizeChooser")[0]);
    ko.cleanNode($('#genderAndSizeChooser')[0]);
    return ko.applyBindings(new imageChooser(), $('#imageChooser')[0]);
  };

  $(document).on('ready page:load', ready);
```

I currently have this code. Somehow, the `ko.cleanNode` code:

```
ko.cleanNode($('#genderAndSizeChooser')[0]);
```

generates an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
```

Anyone have an idea the cause of the error?

Comment: Are you sure that there is actually an element with the `id` of `genderAndSizeChooser`?  The `ko.applyBindings` call would receive undefined and apply bindings to the body like normal, so that would not error, but calling `ko.cleanNode` on undefined would cause an error.

Comment: omg. Please make that an answer. The way applyBindings doesn't actually send any errors. My rails app has overwritten the `id` of the document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it is actually not finding an element with an id of `genderAndSizeChooser`.

The `ko.applyBindings` call would receive `undefined` and apply bindings to the body like normal, so that would not error, but calling `ko.cleanNode` with `undefined` would cause an error.